# OneSignal registration fails after refresh

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, push-notification, push, onesignal

I am using OneSignal in my Laravel/Vue app. I have included it within `<head>` as stated in documentation:

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
            appId: "{{ env('ONESIGNAL_APP_ID') }}"
        });
        OneSignal.showNativePrompt();
    });
</script>

<script>

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/OneSignalSDKWorker.js')
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Service worker registered');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
            });
    } else {
        console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
    }

</script>
```

I also have a service worker of my own, so I've followed the documentation here as well.

What is happening after a hard reset is that service worker gets installed and it is all fine, however once I refresh the page I am getting:

> OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151102:1 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidStateError: The current environment does not support this operation.
> at Function.getServiceWorkerHref (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151102:1:41510)
> at xe. (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151102:1:144028)
> at Generator.next ()
> at r (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151102:1:716)

And I have no idea what does that mean? What is "current environment"? Where to start debugging? I've tried putting console logs around it, however it led me nowhere...

Answer (score 5):

#### You would start debugging by looking at the source code of the library.

In your case your library is the OneSignal SDK for browsers.

**Let's do this!!!**

We can see that this error is thrown by `getServiceWorkerHref` function (which is defined [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/27528f12bcca04787610556286c062098f084c2c/src/helpers/ServiceWorkerHelper.ts#L24)) and the error message is [driven](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/179584ea6035e5c73e68e08c167c94b5c8de64cc/src/errors/InvalidStateError.ts#L35-L37) by the `InvalidStateReason` enumeration:

```js
      case InvalidStateReason.UnsupportedEnvironment:
        super(`The current environment does not support this operation.`);
        break;
```

If you look at the first linked file, you will see the note on `getServiceWorkerHref` OneSignal developers left for the those who dare venture into their source code:

```js
    else if (workerState === ServiceWorkerActiveState.Bypassed) {
      /*
        if the page is hard refreshed bypassing the cache, no service worker
        will control the page.
        It doesn't matter if we try to reinstall an existing worker; still no
        service worker will control the page after installation.
       */
      throw new InvalidStateError(InvalidStateReason.UnsupportedEnvironment);
    }
```

As you can see, the error is raised when the service worker has the "Bypassed" state. What is that, you may ask? Let's look at `ServiceWorkerActiveState` enumeration [below, in the same file](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/27528f12bcca04787610556286c062098f084c2c/src/helpers/ServiceWorkerHelper.ts#L242):

```js
  /**
   * A service worker is active but not controlling the page. This can occur if
   * the page is hard-refreshed bypassing the cache, which also bypasses service
   * workers.
   */
  Bypassed = 'Bypassed',
```

It seems, when the browser "hard-refreshes" the page, it bypasses the service worker and OneSignal can't properly initialize when that happens. Hard-refresh can happen for a number of reasons — here are some of them (to the best of my knowledge):

- if you click the refresh button a bunch of times (usually seconds consecutive refresh within a short period of time may trigger this)
- if you have caching disabled in your DevTools
- if the server sets a `no-cache` header

> What is happening after a hard reset

I don't know exactly what you mean by "hard reset", but that sounds like it would trigger this issue. I would suggest you close your browser and then visit the page you are working on without using "reset" functions — theoretically, the service worker should be used for caching on consecutive visits and that would ensure OneSignal can function.

Comment: So does that mean that I can't do a cmd+shift+R because service worker will never get registered then and I can't rely on functionality be available consistently with my app? If so, this is a big load of bull...

Comment: As far as I can tell, OneSignal won't be able to initialize properly if the service worker doesn't have "control" — and it loses "control" when it is bypassed by hard-refresh. You should file a request with OneSignal support or an issue on their GitHub repository I linked asking for clarification.

Comment: I already contacted support to see what may be the problem. I'll get back to you with an answer, thanks

Comment: @demsey their official explanation is that it is their normal behavior. Hard reload bypasses the worker and causes that error. [This link pasted](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#shift-reload). So no way around it. I am disappointed in the service honestly...